# How to use original Postgres input/output_function in CREATE TYPE?

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have a table with some column of type `smallint` and want to provide a `CAST` from `varchar` to `smallint` to implement some conversions for that column only. So to be able to create a specific `CAST` for my needs, I need a type for that special column. Already tried using a domain, but Postgres warns about those being ignored in a `CAST`... So it looks like I'm stuck with `CREATE TYPE`, but I don't want to implement the required input/output_function on my own, as in the end I only need whatever should already be available for `smallint` in Postgres.

The problem is I don't know the names of those functions, in which lib those are stored, if I need to provide paths which can vary upon installation on different OS or if those are available at all.

So, is it possible to `CREATE TYPE` something like `smallint` which completely only uses Postgres functions and that in a platform/path independent manner?

I didn't find anyone doing something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a type that is just like `smallint` like this:

```
CREATE TYPE myint;

CREATE FUNCTION myintin(cstring) RETURNS myint
   LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'int2in';

CREATE FUNCTION myintout(myint) RETURNS cstring
   LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'int2out';

CREATE FUNCTION myintrecv(internal) RETURNS myint
   LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'int2recv';

CREATE FUNCTION myintsend(myint) RETURNS bytea
   LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'int2send';

CREATE TYPE myint (
   INPUT = myintin,
   OUTPUT = myintout,
   RECEIVE = myintrecv,
   SEND = myintsend,
   LIKE = smallint,
   CATEGORY = 'N',
   PREFERRED = FALSE,
   DELIMITER = ',',
   COLLATABLE = FALSE
);
```

You'd have to define casts to other numeric types if you want to use it in arithmetic expressions.

If you also add casts from `varchar` (or `text`), but beware that creating too many casts can lead to ambiguities and surprising behaviour during type resolution. This is the reason why many type casts were removed in PostgreSQL 8.3, see the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-8-3.html#AEN162638).

I'd recommend that you look for a simpler solution to your problem, such as explicit type casts.

Comment: I want to create a type with two bigint. return one bigint which is a summation of the two bigints.

Comment: @Debjit Creative. Can certainly be done by writing C code (see the example in the documentation).

Comment: Can't we do that using SQL only with no C ?

Comment: Definitely not.